# Dropdown list inside a html table column not working properly

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have used the bootstrap dropdown. The [Senter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upZw5.png) functionality is working properly but it is not getting displayed properly. The drop-down list is getting hidden behind the table rows.

I have tried changed overflow from hidden to visible but not working.
I want to know how I can display the on top of the table.

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: I suspect its because your dropdown is directly inside the <TD> tag which has a width and height and overflow: hidden. Set the css overflow: visible.

Comment: Check the z-index property of the dropdown menu.

Answer (score -1):

```
**<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Si no</th>
   <th> Dropdown</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>
     <selecct>
       <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
     </select>
   </td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>**
```

this is the basic syntax..you can modifly into your project

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).